# how to lock filename

Tags: c#

how to lock filename , so windows users can not change File filename .

Comment: Is it installed? If so, most (non-admin) users won't have (edit) access to the installed files under program-files...? But I'm not very clear *why* you want to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways:

- Use the security permissions to restrict the user from doing so.
- Open the file in exclusive mode, denying any operation on it by any other app.

Unfortunately, none of them is fail-proof... for the good of humanity :)

Comment: How can I Open the file in exclusive mode ?

Comment: Use `File.Open` method with `FileShare` parameter as `None`. Read here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y973b725.aspx

Comment: But you have to keep the file open... if you close, the lock is gone.

Answer (score 2):

Thank God, this is not possible. You may restrict access to this file, so the user won't be able to access it and thus modify its name, but otherwise you cannot prevent them from renaming files.

One more thing, though...

If the file is continuously open in exclusive mode, nobody else will able to modify it, i.e. change its name... But this mean that some process has to lock it, i.e. windows service. Closing such service or killing the process in other way will release the lock.

Answer (score 0):

Think outside the box - use Alternative data streams.

Hide the filename you want in there & have a background task to locate ads with your data stream and restore the 'correct' file name.

### Thats not foolproof either, if the user moves the file to a fat32 volume & back again your ads will be lost.

Think outside the box - write your own file system and install it as an ifs

---

Think outside the box - don't put your data in a file, put it in a database

---

Think outside the box - Trust your users

This is what most of us do.  Helpful error messages at start-up, graceful recovery, perhaps a file dialogue so the user can choose a filename that suits them for reasons you havn't anticipated.

Comment: -1 This is not an answer to the question. Write your own filesystem? And trust your users?? Are you serious? Users are evil, and they want to break your software. Always remember that, and you will make good software.